# Access "repair" breaks a slightly complex query

Tags: ms-access, ado, jet

I have an application that creates an Jet database at run-time, and imports ~100k records so that I can make use of the indexing for performance reasons (1 minute versus nearly 10 when not using a Jet database).

The database is created using ADO Extensibility in Excel, and everything works just fine. However, my issue comes whenever I then open the MDB file in Access front-end, it automatically starts to "repair" the database.

The data is still fine after the "repair", however my main output query can not then be viewed in Access as it tells me it cannot represent the joins, and if I then view it in SQL the required joins are not there, and the query can no longer run. This still happens if I let it get "repaired" but do not open that query, i.e. it is the "repair" that breaks the query, not the act of trying to view it in Access. The funny thing about this is that I used the Access GUI query designer to construct the SQL as my life is too short to worry about it's crazy bracketing style, but it then later decides that it's too complex for itself??

Also, nothing else appears to be affected so I can only assume it's this one query it doesn't like.

This isn't a deal-breaker for me as my fix is to make the MDB hidden and advise users who can see it not to open it.

However, I would really like it if the database could be opened and I didn't have to hide it away like that. Therefore, my question is whether there is any way to prevent the MDB being "repaired" automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be possible to create a DB that does not need to be repaired. Perhaps you could post a little code?

Comment: My code to create the database is just as follows, and I've tested that this alone is enough to force the repair:  
Set objCat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")  
objCat.Create ConnectionString()  

What has occurred to me is that I'm creating an MDB, but opening in Access 2007, which is all I have. Is this likely to be the issue?

Comment: For me, it would be: `objcat.Create "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Z:\Docs\New.accdb;"`

Comment: ConnectionString() returns Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=[FOLDER_PATH]\[DBName].mdb;

Comment: Many thanks for the assistance - does this require Access 07 installed on the machines that create or query it? I know Jet 4 is definitely available on all machines, but the setups are likely to be different as it will be used in various locations

Comment: No, it shouldn't. I am just wondering where the problem is coming from. What happens if you open the newly created database without adding anything else? That is, just run to `objCat.Create ConnectionString()`, do you still find you must repair?

Comment: Yes exactly that, I removed all the CREATE TABLE/PROCEDURE code so I was just creating an empty MDB and it still had to repair it, though happens almost instantly. I am now going to test on a machine without Access 07 using your suggested connection string

Comment: Just a second, the string I posted is for Access 07/10. Your string is for prior to '07. That may be the problem.

Comment: I can't currently get on any machines without Access 07/10, so I have tested just this on an Access 2010 machine obj.Create "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Z:\test.accdb;" and it still repairs it! Maybe I just need to accept that my SQL is too complex for Access (even though it generated it!), so perhaps I'll just use dynamic SQL instead. Thanks for all your help

Comment: I tested on my PC and it worked fine (Access 2010/Windows 7). I wonder if a repair of MS Access is on order?

Comment: Possibly, but I'm getting identical behaviour on 2 different machines, one with Access 07 and the other with Access 10. I can't imagine what is causing that, but I will test on some more machines tomorrow

Comment: It might be worth trying VBScript. Also, I wonder if your install location for MS Access is right for your locale? Check that your New Database Sort Order order in MS Access is set to General - Legacy. You will find it under Options on the General tab.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that. I guess it would make sense that it is to do with an Access setting like that

Comment: Rather than re-creating the Access file in Excel, I would keep the Access file in-tact and re-write the ~100K import in Access instead, is this option available?

Comment: Not really, as I can't be sure all users will have Access installed. Also, I'm trying hard to keep things simple so that I only have to distribute one .xls file to users (Excel is the front-end). However, I have tested further and the repair only happens when opening in Access 07/10 (even when I create an .accdb) but not in Access 03, so must be something to do with the install

Comment: How about this for debugging: create a separate Access database that opens a DAO connection to the "damaged" one and try to see what the query definition is before the database tries to repair itself using the QueryDefs collection. You should also double check that opening the DAO connection does not invoke the auto-repair by opening the "damaged" database afterwords and making sure it still tries to repair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Access is "repairing" the file when opened because it is missing some tables that are specific to the Microsoft Access user interface.  Since you created the MDB file directly using OLEDB with Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0, these tables are not present, and must be created when Access opens the MDB the first time.  There are several ways you can circumvent this:

1)  Name the MDB something other than .mdb - e.g.: `MyAccessDatabase.mad` - this will prevent Windows from using Microsoft Access to open the file.

2)  Use COM+ to open an instance of Microsoft Access, and have it create the .MDB file.  This .MDB file will then have all the necessary tables present and will not need to repair the file.

FYI, whenever Microsoft Access opens an MDB that needs repairing in this fashion, it will inspect all the QueryDef objects for invalid SQL and correct them as necessary.  This is why your "complex" query is breaking.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer. I can't work on the assumption that all users will have Access available so can't implement your suggestion in 2), but now I at least know what causes the issue it gives me peace of mind that I will just need to restate the SQL from my "complex" query if the .MDB ever did get opened. Thanks again